# Look for visual job selection under bash

Tags: bash

To back to job I type:

```
  $ jobs
...
  $ fg 2
```

Is it possible to use menu and select job by arrow and ENTER?

Comment: Also, this probably belongs on the unix/linux forum.

Comment: Bash already have **select** build-in. I hope that exits command with **select** like dialog for **jobs**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, without GUI, is `iselect` (debian has it in its repositories):

```
fg `jobs | iselect -a | grep -o [0-9]*`
```

That would show an interactive textual menu you can select from using arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running gnome, you may display the list in a dialog with `zenity`:

```
fg `jobs | tr '[]' ' \n' | zenity  --list --column '' --column ''`
```

Comment: Thanks. I expect that bash already have some built-in for this, but did not find it.

Answer (score 1):

I used a function in my .bashrc file to foreground jobs with a string match. It's silly but saves me a lot of time.

```
forit() {
    if [ $1 == '']; then
        echo "Please provide an argument";
    else
        fg $(jobs | grep "$1" | sed -n  's/.*\([0-9]\{1,2\}\).*/\1/p')
    fi
}
```